# jQuery anchor scroll... two onclick events

Tags: jquery, onclick, scroll

This is my first post so please let me know if you need more info.

I am using a pagination plugin that generates the links at the bottom of my page content. It outputs the pagination links as below.

```
<a title="Next Page" onclick="appendContent(-2);" class="next scroll" href="#top">next</a>
```

I would also like to use a scroll plugin, so the page scrolls to the top of the content when a pagination link is clicked. The plugin code is as follows...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.scroll").anchorAnimate()
});

jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

settings = jQuery.extend({
    speed : 1100
}, settings);   

return this.each(function(){
    var caller = this
    $(caller).click(function (event) {  
        event.preventDefault()
        var locationHref = window.location.href
        var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

        var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
        $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
            window.location.hash = elementClick
        });
        return false;
    })
})
}
```

The problem i am facing is that because of the onclick="appendContent(-2);" event that the pagination generates, the scroll wont work... i need to somehow combine the two click events. I am not experienced enough with jQuery to work this out, so i am hoping someone may be kind enough to help.

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Could you post the source of your pagination plugin as it will need to be edited to combine them

Comment: I am using the minified version of this plugin...

http://rohitsengar.cueblocks.net/jquery-pagination-plugin/

There is an unminified version here...

http://rohitsengar.cueblocks.net/paginator/download.php?f=paginator_dev.js

I realise this might be a lot to ask... I thought there might be a simple solution. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery to remove your onclick attribute. Before doing that, store it and make your scroll function call it instead.